# 'Pixelated' crumbling sound?

Tags: effect

I have no idea if this is the right place to ask, but I'm doing some animation and I need a sound effect for a character who is pixelated to crumble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at a sound effect generator program, and create the sound yourself.

For example, you can use http://www.bfxr.net/, which is an online tool, no installation required.

You don't need to be an expert to create pretty decent effects. Just click *Randomize* until you get something similar to what you are looking for. Then you can tweak the different sliders until you get it perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Since sound design is no science but art there are multiple ways to evoke a certain impression in the listener/viewer.

What I would use is a bit crusher / distortion effect used on a sine wave that pitches down.

Native Instruments has a extension pack for Guitar Rig that has such an effect unit. It is called [Traktors' 12](http://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/effects/traktors-12/). This comes at a price of 69 EUR. There are free alternatives. Just look around. Maybe your DAW has something like it built in.

Comment: I'm not really looking into equipment or anything, just a simple sound effect.

Comment: So want a ready to go file?

Comment: Yup. That's all I need, a pixelated style crumbling sound.